# Does a Selenium Webdriver recorder exist?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recorder

Does a **recorder for the Selenium 2 WebDriver** exist? For Selenium 1 there has been the IDE as a Firefox plugin. You could record your actions as a script and let them be repeated automatically.

But I'm searching for the same thing for Selenium WebDriver, maybe as a browser plugin or as a desktop application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Selenium IDE records your actions and the script it creates can be **either** Selenium v1 or Selenium v2 (WebDriver).

This is done via the settings in the IDE, when you export the test case it'll ask what kind of script you want it to be.

Comment: You're right, thanks: Export TestCase as --> select C# / NUnit / WebDriver or C# / NUnit / RemoteControl

Answer (score 2):

You can try Selenium-builder which is add-on to Firefox.An open source tool for easily writing automated Selenium scripts and running those cross-browser in the cloud.You can get this tool below link

https://saucelabs.com/builder