# Is there a Web-UI out there for creating test's using htmlunit?

Tags: htmlunit

I want to be able to create the test's inside the Web-UI instead of writing them in code. Also i want to automate the tests and have extensive reporting.
I am restricted to htmlunit because the websites i am testing are testable with htmlunit.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the test steps in other ways, see [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16779274/184201) recorder, [WebTest](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/WebTestHome.html) and [Wetator](http://www.wetator.org/).

There is [Spring MVC Test HtmlUnit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-htmlunit) also.